Why is my character's arm moving when I move the core bone?
Dear Blender Exchange people, i'm working on animating a character for a game i'm working on, and I had animated walking animations for every direction. After I finished those, I made an idle animation for the shotgun. For some reason, when I play the walking animation, the hands, which are attached to the shotgun through "child of" constraints, move up and down when the player core bone moves up and down. The shotgun is attached to the head bone, for easier first person animation. How can I stop the arm from moving up and down, and have it stay connected to the gun? (I'll attach a gif of the issue below).


hello could you please share the armature so that we can give a try?

I'm not sure how to do that

use https://blend-exchange.com/ (read the instructions)



The bones called Bicep.R and ArmTarget.R are parented to Head, which makes no sense, parent Bicep.R to Spine2 and parent ArmTarget.R to a root bone. For the moment ArmTarget.R is moved by 2 parents: Head + the bone of the gun (via the Child Of constraint), it makes it move twice.

I had the bicep parented to the head so that the arms wouldn't look distorted if the player looked up or down, I got it to work by detaching the target from the head tho, thanks so much!
